# OpenSSL compile from source using Cmake?

Tags: c++, openssl, cmake, cross-platform

I would like to pull in OpenSSL to our cross platform project and compile from source code.  We have many platforms (Windows, Mac, iOS, Android, Xamarin Andriod)  so using maintaining/updating binaries can be a headache.  We are using cmake.

Has anyone successfully used Cmake to compile OpenSSL?  Is there any example?

Comment: I found the following which may be helpful. https://gist.github.com/jcfr/6030240

Jc is using this script to do uploads with the Openssl, but perhaps you can farm the bits related to OpenSSL. Jc is a good CMake programmer!

Comment: Take a look at this project: https://github.com/ruslo/hunter. OpenSSL builds fine for Windows (Visual Studio), Linux, Mac (+iOS).

Comment: Cross platform C++ package management!  That's awesome.  I will give it a go when I get a chance.

Answer (score 3):

openssl-cmake([1](https://launchpad.net/openssl-cmake)) project is an option. This provides a cmake build system for openssl. You are also no more dependent on PERL.

Answer (score 0):

## Compiling OpenSSL from source using CMake

OpenSSL and for that matter Boost each have their own build systems which it would be neither wise nor valuable to mess with. So when you say compile them you mean you want to call their build systems from CMake. This can be done with `ExternalProject_Add` and usually some sort of scripting glue using for example `Bash`.

An example might be my https://github.com/palmerc/CMake_OpenSSL project that compiles OpenSSL for iOS. This could easily be a general template for any library with its own build system.